# how to get jqgrid visible row's data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, row, visible

I have a jqgrid on my page.In which some rows are visible and some are not visible based on some condition.

And there is one status column in jqgrid which maintain the status of row's visibility.

> > And my problem is ,I am not able to get only visible rows by getRowData() function.
> >
> > Also I want  only visible row's id's with jqGrid('getDataIDs')

Update :

Below is code by which I am getting grid row id's :

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```

Below is code by which I am getting grid row's :

```
$("#myGrid").getRowData();
```

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Is it `datatype: "local"`? Is "visible" is the part of data? You should just include at least part of JavaScript code which you use and test data and explain of the test data what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Oleg,I have tried this to get only visible row's data :
$("#myGrid").getRowData().find("tr:visible");

but its not working.